# How to edit and run client side html/javascript source of third-party web application?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, reactjs, web-applications

There is a third-party web application. The server side is developed using Java spring technology and the client side is implemented in AngularJS/HTML/CSS. The client side code is minified. We don't have access to the source files and so we can't build and run the server. I want a few changes to be made in the javascript and HTML files. What are the ways to achieve this? Can we edit the minified files and html files after stopping the server? This is just for reverse engineering purpose.

Comment: You should be able to edit the minified files at any point. Starting/stopping matters only if the resources are cached, so changing the file in the file system won't modify what the server returns. Not sure if that's the case for you or not. Still, assuming the server just reads from the disk and serves that content, you can do live changes and just refresh the page.

Comment: Can we edit html files?. Is there any tool?

Comment: Same applies to HTML files. Just edit them and verify they are not served from some sort of cache. The "tool" is whatever editor you prefer. There are some tools (plugins for editors or standalone ones) that will prettify the code...which is mostly auto-indenting it.